# QtNetworkRequest cause program to "finish unexpectedly"

Tags: c++, qt

I'm a beginner in C++ and Qt and I'm trying to make a translation program but it crashes upon the network request execution...

The error:
*Oversetter.exe exited with code 255*

My code:

**Header file**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QApplication>
...
#include <QUrl>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkRequest>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkReply>
#include <QtScript/QScriptEngine>
#include <QtScript/QScriptValue>
#include <QtScript/QScriptValueIterator>

class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
MainWindow();

public slots:
void getTranslation();
void onTranslationRecieved(QNetworkReply* reply);

private:
QTextEdit *te_input;
QTextEdit *te_output;
};
#endif
```

**Code file**

```
void MainWindow::getTranslation()
{
te_output->setText("[Oversettelse pågår]\n[Translation in progress]");

QString url = "http://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx";
...
url.append(te_input->toPlainText());
qInfo() << "url: " + url;

QNetworkAccessManager *nam;
connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(onTranslationRecieved(QNetworkReply*)));
nam->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)));

}

void MainWindow::onTranslationRecieved(QNetworkReply* reply)
{
QString data = (QString) reply->readAll();
te_output->setText(data);

QScriptEngine engine;
QScriptValue result = engine.evaluate(data);
QString translation = result.property("0").property("0").property("0").toString();
}
```

Any help will be very appreciated :-)

Comment: Can you put the class definition of MainWindow ? Like this, i'd say you forgot to initialize one of your pointer member and it causes a seg fault

Comment: You never initialize `QNetworkAccessManager *nam;` !? That's an invalid pointer you try to access.

Comment: Also you might want to use [JSON Support in Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html) to parse the result, instead of using the `QScriptEngine`, if you're using Qt 5 at least.

Comment: @RD41 Qt has quite good examples in the documentation of all classes: see this http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#details

Comment: Thank you, it seems to have solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For first:

the line

```
QNetworkAccessManager *nam;
```

Should be:

```
QNetworkAccessManager *nam = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
```